# Multi stream SCP to transfer large amount of small files from EC2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, scp

I am using `scp` to download millions of small files (100 - 1000 kb) files from my EC2 instances. `scp` seems to transfer one file at a time and does not utilize fully my 1 gbps connection.

Is there a more efficient way to download the files? For various technical reasons, achieving and downloading is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It can also work through ssh.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still able to use `tar`, but not able to create a tarball on the remote host, you can try something like:

```
ssh ec2instance "tar c /path/to/source" | tar x -C /path/to/destination
```

You can use the `v` option to `tar`, or the [pipe viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to get feedback on the transfer.

**If the above is not an option either**, try running several (a dozen) `scp` in parallel to reduce the effect of the overhead induced by many small files.

(Also make sure that the filesystem is not the bottleneck.)